# Working with several repositories at the same time with Subversive in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I would like to use two svn repositories. One is to synchronize with my production environment and the other is to synchronize with another developer. Is it possible using Subversive in Eclipse?

EDIT: Sorry! I meant SVN, not CVS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you means is "For one given project, I would like to be able to synchronise on one side with the official repo and at the same time, use the synchronisation and merging facilities to stay i sync with another CVS repository".

Best of my knowledge, this is not possible from the same project.  Neither with CVS nor with subversion nor with any other SCM.  This is a little bit because all SCM plugins are actually plugged into the Team Management plugins of eclipse and has actually a lot to do with the fact that the relation between a dev environment and a repository is quite exclusive.

What you have to do if you want to synchronize on an exceptional basis is :

1. Disconnect from one repo (say CVS) (team disconnect).  Do not delete the .cvs folders.
2. Reconnect to a second repo (say SVN - either subversive or subclipse <= my preferred one)
3. Synch with SVN
4. disconnect from SVN
5. reconnect with CVS (team => share).

This is too risky to be done on a regular basis.

Therefore there are other strategies

1. Use a "shadow project" in your workspace synchronised through a regular synchronisation tool. The master project being connected to the CVS repo and the shadow to VN.
2. Use git + SVN.  git as your local repo backed by SVN.  The other developer can use a similar approach.

All in all there are no simple "out of the box" solution.  All these solutions require a significant amount of commitment to work flawlessly.  But SCM has always been like this, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to use Subversive in Eclipse. I am using Subversion and CVS both through Eclipse and Tortoise. Subversion is much faster and seems to handle binary files better. The one thing to get your head around is that revision numbering is totally different between subversion and cvs. May be [this](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/install.php) can help you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Subversive adds [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)
  integration for Eclipse (subversion
  is a version control system similar
  to CVS). It does not handle CVS
  repositories!!!
- To use CVS repositories with eclipse
  you should use the [appropriate CVS
  Plugin for eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-cvs/h).

You may even use both eclipse plugins ([subversive](http://subversion.apache.org/) and the [cvs](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-cvs/h) plugin). They will work with Eclipse like a charm (but keep in mind that subversive only handles subversion repositories).